# Symfony2: cache busting and versioning assets with Assetic

Tags: php, symfony, caching, assets, assetic

Who knows how to add versions to assets that was loaded inside Assetic blocks globally ?

Added to my config.yml

```
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
    assets_version: v2
```

it works for regular assets, but doesn't for asset_url inside stylesheets and javascripts assetic blocks 
Am I doing somethg wrong or it's some kind of a bug ?

small upd.
it doesn't work without assets_version_format

Comment: Have you read the docs? http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#ref-framework-assets-version

Comment: didn't work with assetic bundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It works for me.**

config.yml:

```
framework:
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        assets_version: 1.0.1
        assets_version_format: '%%s?v=%%s'
```

Example:

```
{% javascripts '@DashboardBundle/Resources/public/js/config.js' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Result:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/config.js?v=1.0.1"></script>
```

---

**If you want to test in dev environment:**

config_dev.yml:

```
assetic:
    use_controller: false
```

app_dev.php :

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', false);
```

Then in your terminal:

```
php app/console assets:install
php app/console assetic:dump
php app/console cache:clear --env=dev --no-debug
```